# JSON.stringify on a react element converts it to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a react element `testReactElement` and want to display it on the screen and even after the user closes the tab and opens it again, they should find the same data still displayed, so I put it on the localStorage, and to add a react element to localStorage I first should stringify it using  `JSON.stringify()` , and It gets successfully stored in `localstorage`, when I want to retrieve it from the local storage and display it It, I use  `JSON.parse()`.

```
import './App.css';
let testReactElement = <div>
    <h1>this is the title of the react element</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the react element</p>
  </div>
  localStorage.setItem('element',JSON.stringify(testReactElement))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('element'))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The problem is that  `JSON.parse()` returns a javascript object the looks similar to but not the same as the react element I initially added to localStorage, and the newly returned object is missing some keys, so react doesn't recognize it as a react element, and throws the following error  `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
When I tried to compare the original react element to the stringified one , I found that after the stringification, the react element is missing the '$$typeof' symbol key and is what causes react not to recognize it as a react element and only see it as a regular JS object, therefore throwing an error . After some googling, I found that this happens because when we try JSON.stringify(symbol) it returns `undefined`.
So how can I put a react element in `localstorage` and then retrieve it back as I initially entered it so I can display it on the screen?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't store certain values (functions, undefined) so this isn't going to work. You're better off storing a copy of the *state* of the component and then restoring the component accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You should make use of useEffect when you try to get the items from local storage and not do it in jsx. 
**[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-iqcgk?file=/src/App.js:93-131)**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

let testReactElement = "this is the title of the react element";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(testReactElement);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("data");
    if (data) {
      setData(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
  });

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}
export default App;
```